# How do you demolish a building in Knights and Merchants?

Tags: knights-and-merchants

This is an ancient game, but how do you demolish a building in *K&M*?  It seems to be pretty obvious to some, yet I don't see an intuitive way at all.

Comment: Are you trying to demolish a friendly building, an enemy building, or are you asking about both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Friendly - and I just finally found the option yesterday, it's in the building menu. Spent so much time looking for it!

Comment: haha. Also interesting thing is you cannot demolish a building when the builders are digging in the ground but as soon as they are done digging (before they start building) you can. When you demolish a building like that you will get a 'free' road square in the entrance (i say free because you dont pay any stone but your builder wastes time digging in all the squares of the building it still might be faster than building road depending how long stone delivery will take) Hope this helps someone :D